# Applying CSS on hover to multiple components

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a shape which consists of 3 components:

```
       *  *****************************  *
     ***  *                           *  ***
   *****  *                           *  *****
 *******  *****************************  *******
```

As shown in the diagram above, the shape consists of a rectangle surrounded by two triangles (one on the left side and one on the right).

I would like the entire shape to change to the same colour whenever the user hovers over any one of its components.

I've tried using various methods to accomplish this task but without much success.

Here's what I currently have [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harishkumar/svzrkdu6/5/).

The shape is kind of off, however my main concern is how to get the hover feature working for my object.

Even though I tried implementing JavaScript in the fiddle above, I will accept any other alternative methods that will get my code working.

Comment: the thing to do would be to declare the color on a parent rather than on the children.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a6p924od/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your JSFiddle was not displaying the .slopeRight, I added the following html:

```
.slopeRight {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #D8D8D8;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 255px;                                
}
```

I then surrounded all the rectangle components under one div called .wrap, and added the following css:

```
.wrap:hover .tabStyle {
    backGround: red;
    border-color: red;
}

.wrap:hover .slopeLeft {
    border-color: transparent red red transparent ;
}

.wrap:hover .slopeRight {
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/svzrkdu6/10/

Moreover, are you sure you want 3 components to your shape? Because if not, you may create a trapezoid instead, which is much more concise...check out this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/383rksx6/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot man Bolboa <3 <3

Answer (score 3):

I've done it like here:

```
<div class="container">
    ... your code    
</div>


.container:hover .tabStyle{
    background : #000;
    border-color: #000;
}

.container:hover .slopeLeft, .container:hover .slopeRight{
    border-bottom-color: #000;
}
```

where .container is parent element for your div's

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/svzrkdu6/12/

Comment: you didn't use any css for his .slopeRight, note that OP specifies that there are two triangles and one rectangle that he wishes to modify. Your css only modifies the left triangle and the rectangle...

Answer (score 2):

It is achievable using pure CSS. Modify your code line:

```css
/* Just for an example */
.child {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

/* Your solution */
.parent:hover .child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child first">A</div>
  <div class="child second">B</div>
  <div class="child third">C</div>
</div>
```